# Automapper - Cannot ignore a property when mapping to a list existing entities

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I have two class `TenantRestrictSourceEntity`, `TenantRestrictSource` and mapper profile

```
CreateMap<TenantRestrictSourceEntity, TenantRestrictSource>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Tenant, opt => opt.Ignore());

public class TenantRestrictSourceEntity
{
    public string SourceType { get; set; }
    public bool? Enable { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TenantRestrictSource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SourceType { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

When I map one `TenantRestrictSourceEntity` to one `TenantRestrictSource` with `Mapper.Map(tenantRestrictSourceEntity, tenantRestrictSource)`. Everything works fine. Tenant property was ignored correctly.

But when I try to map a list `TenantRestrictSourceEntity` to a list `TenantRestrictSource` with `Mapper.Map(tenantRestrictSourceEntities, tenantRestrictSources)` Tenant property is always `null`.

How can I ignore that property when mapping a list object?

Comment: did you tried Mapper.Map<List<tenantRestrictSources>>(tenantRestrictSourceEntities) ?

Comment: It will create a new list, I want to map to an existing list

Comment: I made a simple app to test it and it worked with AutoMapper 7.0.1.0

Comment: Lists are cleared before mapping, try AutoMapper.Collection.